# Saving a double value to Access Database From C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, double

So I'm creating a simple database reader which is only supposed to get values from an access database into a DataGridView. I connected them with the built in help to get a DataSource if you know what I mean. And everything is fine but on the "Value" column when I write down let's say 1172,44 it will save it as 117244 in access and so, when I open it on the application the value is 117244 since it's the saved value.

Both in access and in the c# dataset the fieldsize property is set as double. I've tried as decimal but it just gives me an error which I can't find out what's causing it. Seems like to me that it is not reading "," as a comma but as a "." which most likely makes it a thousand-separator and just removes it resulting in the number without the comma. Anyone knows how i could fix it ? I can get any code you need here you just have to ask.

Thanks, Bruno Charters. (=

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the double value stored in the DataSet to be culture-independent (invariant) and control the representation of the group and decimal separators. One way to do this is parsing the input using the `CultureInfo` format provider. The code below illustrates the conversion of `"1172,44"` into `1172.44d`

```
var culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "."; 
var a = double.Parse("1172,44", culture);

Console.WriteLine(a); //outputs 1172.44
```

Comment: Is it possible to just set the cultureinfo before the application runs or on the loading so that i don't need to parse it. Oh and btw, i'm using C# windows form mode. (: So i don't really understand some of the code you wrote. Thank you!

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine` code was just to test the results easily when running the code thru LinqPad. Also you could try setting `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture` using the culture defined above, but I am not sure this will work for you or be the best way to handle things if it did.

Comment: Apparently it won't recognize the "CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture". Do i have to add any specific library? I've searched and end up adding the system.Globalization one but seems not to be enough. Thanks for helping once again (:

Comment: Edit: I found the library, i think it's system.threading; but i had to create `public static Thread CurrentThread { get; set;}` and not sure it will work still. Trying it out now !

Comment: Didn't work it out, i add the code you gave me into 

`public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            this.dataGridView1.DataError += this.DataGridView_DataError;
            var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "."; 
            CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        }`

Is that the correct place? I understand it would be used to parse, but where can i get to parse it?

Comment: Here's what i came up with and it didn't work and it's exactly what you did up there but with the number taken from the **DataGridView**.

`var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();

culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

string conversor = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(); //gets the value out of the gridview
var a = double.Parse(conversor, culture);
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = a;`

Getting real annoyed by this... Why so hard microsoft ? :OOO

Comment: @BrunoCharters, What about using the **[CellParsing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx)** of the DataGridView, using the code in my answer there? As an aside, I'm not sure why you need the CurrentThread property, you should just be able to say `System.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, but I'm pretty sure this isn't going to help, and would instead look at some event on the grid itself to implement the parsing.

Comment: Is it possible to handle it for a single collumn? Let's say, mine's called "Value". And, about `System.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` it won't recognize currentthread even. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: In the CellParsing event, you should be able to make the parsing code apply only to the "Value" column by saying: `if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Value") ...`. There is an example in the link to the CellParsing event on MSDN that gives an example.

Comment: And then use the code you gave me ? (: Looks promising .

Comment: `if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Valor")
{
 if (e.Value != null)
{
try
{
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
e.Value = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString(), culture);
e.ParsingApplied = true;
}
catch (FormatException)
{
 e.ParsingApplied = false;
}
}`

Didn't work. Maybe it's me doing it wrong . Want me to make it available somewhere on the internet so you can check it out ? :O I'll handle database too . Small Files so .

Comment: I don't think it is actually running the CellParsing event, i added a messagebox at the end saying done if the try was successful but it never pops but, nor does in the catch so i'm kinda confused. This is supposed to be simple i think, i'm pretty sure there's some configuration or setting i'm missing completely .

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture that the comma is being interpreted as a group separator is probably correct.  You may want to double-check the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture of your process, and possibly the regional settings of your computer, as well as the format properties of the Access database, if they have been set.

I suspect you should read [How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hezscd0d.aspx).  The system is somewhat complicated, but it should give you the flexibility to impose a specific format on your UI, if you can't do it with the appropriate culture settings.

Comment: I have tried to create a "mask" for it. And it does give me the same errors, it converts it from 1172,44 to 117244. Thing is, is it possible to, create an event handler for when i finish entering a value in the Datagridview collumn. Like, parsing the value with Matt's code in the above answear to my post, when i press enter in the datagridview "Value" collumn. Thank you again (: